# URL Rewrite - PHP & Apache

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have links like

```
<li><a href="search.php?domainid=5&cat=electronic">Electronic</a></li>
```

How can I change it to

```
<li><a href="electronic.html">Electronic</a></li>
```

I have more than 50 categories.

I am using Apache web server and PHP 5.5. Need dynamic URL Rewrite for SEO friendly URL.

```
<li><a href="search.php?domainid=5&cat=electronic">Electronic</a></li>
```

this need to be

```
<li><a href="electronic.html">Electronic</a></li>
```

and

```
<li><a href="search.php?domainid=13&cat=gifts">Gifts</a></li>
```

this need to be

```
<li><a href="gifts.html">Gifts</a></li>
```

and

```
<li><a href="search.php?domainid=4&cat=food">Food</a></li>
```

this need to be

```
<li><a href="food.html">Food</a></li>
```

and

```
<li><a href="search.php?domainid=11&cat=home-decore">Home Decore</a></li>
```

this need to be

```
<li><a href="home-decore.html">Home Decore</a></li>
```

and

```
<li><a href="search.php?domainid=3&cat=hotels-travels">Hotels & Travel</a></li>
```

this need to be

```
<li><a href="hotels-travels.html">Hotels & Travel</a></li>
```

and so on...

Comment: You tagged this with `.htaccess` so am I correct that you're using Apache as your webserver?

Comment: Do you mean dynamically, like with javascript?

Comment: This has to be dynamic and wanted using .htaccess

Answer (score 1):

Here's the full solution

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^([a-z]*)\.html /search.php?domainid=5&cat=$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

It's only a few lines but there's alot going on here so let's break down what's each little bit does

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
```

This line just opens a stanza (block) to indicate that Apache should only execute the directives inside if the specified module is loaded. In this case, the **mod_rewrite** module.

```
  RewriteEngine on
```

Pretty simple, just turns on url-rewriting in case it already wasn't

```
  RewriteRule ^/([a-z]*)\.html /search.php?domainid=5&cat=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This is where all the work happens, and it's a bit complex so I'll break it down further. First, [the anatomy of a rewrite rule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

> RewriteRule *Pattern Substitution [flags]*

So let's first look at the *Pattern*

```
^/([a-z]+)\.html
```

RewriteRule patterns are [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) - if you aren't already familiar with those I'm afraid you'll have to do some independent study as they are much to large a topic to cover here. But what I will say is that this pattern is designed to match any URI that starts at the root and has one-or-more contiguous lower-case alpha characters followed by `.html`. So it would match all of these

```
/electronic.html
/electronic.html?referrer=facebook
/analog.html
/somethingelse.html
```

But *would not* match any of these

```
/category/electronic.html # Because it's not root relative
/cat5.html                # Because of the number
/something-else.html      # Because of the hyphen
/Electronic.html          # Because of the capital E
```

So as you can see, regex patterns are very explicit and sensitive, so you'll need a full understanding of the nature of your category names in order to author a proper RewriteRule pattern.

Another thing to note in this pattern is the parentheses around the contiguous alpha characters - that creates a "captured subgroup" which can be referenced in the *Substitution* portion of the RewriteRule, we we need so let's look at that next

```
/search.php?domainid=5&cat=$1
```

This tells the rewrite engine to take matched urls and internally rewrite them to according to the above pattern. See the `$1`? That's the captured subgroup we got in the *Pattern* so it will be replaced by whatever the captured characters were.

The last part is the *[flags]*

- `L` simply means "Last" which tells mod_rewrite to not try to rewrite the URL again
- `QSA` is "Query String Append" which will ensure that query-string data in the requested URL will survive to the rewritten one. For example, `/electronic.html?referrer=facebook` would be rewritten to `/search.php?domainid=5&cat=electronic&referrer=facebook`

And that's it! You'll almost certainly need to modify this to suit your needs 100%, but I hope this is enough to get you started.

### EDIT

Here are some alternate patterns that will match different category names

- `^/([a-z-]+)\.html` Allows hyphens
- `^/([a-zA-Z]+)\.html` Allows capital letters
- `^/([a-z0-9]+)\.html` Allows numbers
- `^/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\.html` Allows all of the above

Comment: I have updated question please check.

Comment: To accomodate categories with hyphens, that's just a small change to the pattern - I'll add a note at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

A really niave example `.htaccess` might contain:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ search.php?domainid=5&cat=$1 [L]
```

**Edit**: Regarding the `domainid` param, you have a couple options:

- Add more rules to translate from say `%{HTTP_HOST}` to whatever id the domain maps to.
- Modify `search.php` to figure it out from say `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`.

The latter is probably the sane thing to do.

Comment: I have updated question please check.